# How to format header in `tufte-book`?

Tags: geometry, tufte

I'm putting together a `tufte-book` whose page size is 5.5'' * 8.5''. I have most of the geometry worked out, but the page headers aren't cooperating. So I have this stuff in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,width=4in,textwidth=3in,textheight=6in,top=1in,left=1in,right=1.5in}
```

Which produces an OK text block, but headers cut off by the edge of the page (see screenshot). What's the remedy?[image]

### Update

Verso pages now look OK; on recto pages the header is still truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer was to play around with `marginparwidth` and `marginparsep` in the `geometry` parameters. The magic numbers, for posterity, were:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,textwidth=4.5in,textheight=6in,marginparwidth=2cm,marginparsep=2mm,top=1in,left=0.75in,right=1.5in}
```